# how to use when with a subject

Tags: questions

I'm learning English and I have question about how to use when in a question.

for ex- if I want to ask someone when is the child school closes for holiday. how should I frame the question and which is the correct sentence structure to use.

Comment: "When does the school close for the holidays?" Since the school year is divided into three _terms_, many people would say "When does term end?" or "When is the end of term?"

Answer (score 1):

The right way to say it would be "When does the school close for the holidays?".

Generally speaking, if "when" is used in a question, it is almost always placed at the beginning of the sentence.